# django apache mod wsgi 500 internal server error on form submittion MYSQL

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-deployment

So I've deployed django on vps with apache and mod wsgi. Everything seems to work fine except for one thing. Whenever I try to submit any of my forms, I get 500 server error. No errors show up in apache's errors log which is really weird.

Also before this on form submission I was getting errors that mod wsgi is running one version of python and other is being ran mod wsgi. I fixed this by ./configure'ing mod wsgi.

please let me know if you need anything else.

Here's my apache conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin marijus.merkevicius@gmail.com
        ServerName 5.199.166.109
        WSGIDaemonProcess ts threads=25
        WSGIProcessGroup ts
        Alias /static /home/tshirtnation/staticfiles
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/tshirtnation/index.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

mod wsgi:

import os
import sys
import site

```
# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/home/tshirtnation')
sys.path.append('/home/tshirtnation/tshirtnation')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tshirtnation.settings'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Okay, so I figured out that it's because of the database because I am using different db in development and it works fine.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'tshirtnation',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'HOST': '5.199.166.109',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

here are my settings. am I doing something wrong ?

Edit:

tried on development with production database and everything worked :/ I absoutely have no idea where this error is coming from..

Comment: Probably a [Cross Site Request Forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) issue.

Comment: @alecxe I've put csrf tokens in my forms. And they do work in development..

Comment: Ok, could you please check if setting `DEBUG` to `True` makes it work?

Comment: @alecxe still the same error, no error messages and error logs are clean :/

Comment: @alecxe also login form somehow works :o

Comment: Have you checked apache error logs?

Comment: @alecxe yeah they're clean